# How to serve dev version of angularapp in grunt?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am trying to serve my angular app with grunt and express. Currently the serve task looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.registerTask('serve', function(target) {

        // Default task
        grunt.task.run([
            'clean',
            // init
            //'concurrent:init',
            // compile html, styles, and scripts
            //'concurrent:compile',

            // 'uglify',
            // 'Karma',
            'express:server',
            'open:browser',
            'watch'
        ]);

    });
};
```

I just want to serve the angular app without any copying, minification etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### A simplest way

I suggest that you use to use [Browserify](http://browserify.org) which is one of the simplest way to serve a JS app via Grunt. Here is an example that supposes your JS application is in an `src` directory with an `index.html` at its root :

**grunfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    browserSync: {
      bsFiles: {
        src: './src/**/*'
      },
      options: {
        server: './src'
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserSync']);
};
```

You obviously need to install *grunt-browser-sync* before (`npm i -D grunt-browser-sync`).

---

#### With Express

If you still wish to use express because that's you'll do in production, I suggest you the [**grunt-express** plugin](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express), there is a complete example app using [Angular, Express and Grunt here](https://github.com/blai/grunt-express-angular-example). It's 3 years old but is still working for an actual Angular + Express application.